# How can I select current event class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page called profile.php and on this page I have 4 form for user to update. I used `.validation` class for all 4 form. I used this for jQuery `beforeSend()`. So that when a form is press it will be show `Validation...` text.

Now I use `user_profile_data()` on 2 forms. When I update the form it's showing `Validation...` text on 2 form. BUT it's should be show on selected form.

**Here is jQuery/Js I am using :**

```
function user_profile_data (element,event){
    e= $(element);
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(e.parents('form')[0]);  
    $.ajax({
      url: 'user_profile_data',
      type: 'POST',
      xhr: function() {
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        return myXhr;
      },
      beforeSend: function () {
        $('.validation').val('Validating...');
        $("#avator_upload").attr("disabled", true);
        $('.account_validation_msg').html('<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>Validating...</strong></div>');
      },
      success: function (data) {                          
        $('.account_validation_msg').html(data);                      
        $('#notification_bottom').val('SAVE DETAILS');
        $('.account_validation_msg').show();
        $("#avator_upload").attr("disabled", false);                 
      },

      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
  }); 
}
```

Comment: `e.closest('form')` would be the form, so use it to filter it, e.g: `e.closest('form').find('.validation').val('Validating...');`

Comment: let me try with this.

Comment: @Wolf it's worked :)

Comment: Can I attached an image instead of `validating...` text ? like loading.gif